# Using Knockoutjs Mapping Plugin inside viewmodel constructor

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am trying to use the mapping plugin inside the constructor so I can easily add other functions to the constructor and have the observable items automatically created from the mapping plugin.  Here is the code that I currently have but it is neither mapping the observable variables that I provide it or including the 'save' function in the end viewmodel.  Is there a better way to do this?

```
function ViewModel(model){
        var self = this;

        self = ko.mapping.fromJS(model);

        self.save = function() {
            var data = ko.toJSON(self);
            $.post("/Licensing/edit", data, function(returnedData) {
                // This callback is executed if the post was successful
            });
        }

    };

    var vm = new ViewModel(model);
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is not working because `ko.mapping.fromJS(model);` returns a new object what you assign to your `self` local variable what you extend with the `save` function.

However this new object is not returned from your constructor function so you will end with with an empty object because not the originally passed in `this` is modified.

You can fix this with returning `self` from your constructor:

```
function ViewModel(model){
    var self = this;

    self = ko.mapping.fromJS(model);

    self.save = function() {
        var data = ko.toJSON(self);
        $.post("/Licensing/edit", data, function(returnedData) {
            // This callback is executed if the post was successful
        });
    }

    return self;
};
```

Or you can tell the mapping plugin to don't create a new object just use the currently created one with passing `self` as the third argument:

```
function ViewModel(model){
    var self = this;

    ko.mapping.fromJS(model, {}, self);

    self.save = function() {
        var data = ko.toJSON(self);
        $.post("/Licensing/edit", data, function(returnedData) {
            // This callback is executed if the post was successful
        });
    }

};
```

Comment: I knew it was something trivial, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to use a constructor (using `new`). You're not going to make multiple instances or have a prototype. Just use the object `ko.mapping` creates for you.

```
function ViewModel(model){
    var self = ko.mapping.fromJS(model);

    self.save = function() {
        var data = ko.toJSON(self);
        $.post("/Licensing/edit", data, function(returnedData) {
            // This callback is executed if the post was successful
        });
    }
    return self;
};

var vm = ViewModel(model);
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also save is an private method, write save like that :

> self._save = function() {
>            }